# Hide images outside of view in image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hide, carousel

I made an image slider but I have a problem. İf you click the next button, it doesn't hide the image on the left side of the slider.

The code is here :

http://codepen.io/ardazaman/pen/zBGMJX

HTML:

```
 <section id="slider">
            <div class="arrow">
                <a href="#"> < </a>
                <a href="#"> > </a>
            </div>

            <div class="slider">
                <ul>
                    <li class="slides"><img src="resimler/resim1.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="slides"><img src="resimler/resim2.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="slides"><img src="resimler/resim3.jpg"></li>
                    <li class="slides"><img src="resimler/resim4.jpg"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>   


  </section>
```

CSS:

```
section#slider {
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  width: 1004px;
  height: 575px;
  position: relative;
}

div.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
}

div.slider ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.slider ul li {
  width: 960px;
  float: left;
}

div.slider ul li img {
  width: 960px;
}

div.arrow {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
}

div.arrow a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}

div.arrow a:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

div.arrow a:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 870px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var liWidth = $('div.slider ul li').width();
  var toplamLi = $('div.slider ul li').length;
  var toplamWidth = liWidth * toplamLi;
  var liDeger = 0;

  $('div.slider ul').css({
    width: toplamWidth + "px"
  });

  $('div.arrow a:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
    if (liDeger < toplamLi - 1) {
      liDeger++;
      toplamWidth = liDeger * liWidth;
      $('div.slider ul').animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + toplamWidth + "px"
      }, 500);
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('div.arrow a:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
    if (liDeger > 0) {
      liDeger--;
      toplamWidth = liDeger * liWidth;
      $('div.slider ul').animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + toplamWidth + "px"
      }, 500);
    }
    return false;
  });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes done only to CSS:
1.

```
div.slider ul {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; //added

}
```

and 2.

```
div.slider {
  margin: 14px auto 0; //added
}
```

rest is same

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var liWidth = $('div.slider ul li').width();
  var toplamLi = $('div.slider ul li').length;
  var toplamWidth = liWidth * toplamLi;
  var liDeger = 0;

  $('div.slider ul').css({
    width: toplamWidth + "px"
  });

  $('div.arrow a:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
    if (liDeger < toplamLi - 1) {
      liDeger++;
      toplamWidth = liDeger * liWidth;
      $('div.slider ul').animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + toplamWidth + "px"
      }, 500);
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('div.arrow a:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
    if (liDeger > 0) {
      liDeger--;
      toplamWidth = liDeger * liWidth;
      $('div.slider ul').animate({
        marginLeft: '-' + toplamWidth + "px"
      }, 500);
    }
    return false;
  });

});
```

```css
section#slider {
  margin-left: 150px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  width: 1004px;
  height: 575px;
  position: relative;
}

div.slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 960px;
  margin: 14px auto 0;
}

div.slider ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

div.slider ul li {
  width: 960px;
  float: left;
}

div.slider ul li img {
  width: 960px;
}

div.arrow {
  font-size: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
}

div.arrow a {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align:center;
}

div.arrow a:nth-child(1) {
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}

div.arrow a:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 870px;
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="slider">
  <div class="arrow">
    <a href="#">
      &lsaquo; </a>
        <a href="#"> &rsaquo; </a>
  </div>

  <div class="slider">
    <ul>
      <li class="slides"><img src="http://i.hizliresim.com/o78oE9.jpg"></li>
      <li class="slides"><img src="http://i.hizliresim.com/l1rmEr.jpg"></li>
      <li class="slides"><img src="http://i.hizliresim.com/VYXmEv.jpg"></li>
      <li class="slides"><img src="http://i.hizliresim.com/nrmZEM.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>


</section>
```

And here's the codepen link [on codepen](http://codepen.io/link2pk/pen/KMpbzb)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to keep track of which image you are showing, and hide the rest by CSS. You already know the index of the list item that contains it (`liDeger`), so you can use that to show the correct image and hide all the others.

The important part is that you want to show the new image as soon as the sliding starts, but only hide the previous one *after* the sliding ends.

So for example the "next" arrow:

```
$('div.arrow a:nth-child(2)').click(function() {
    if (liDeger < toplamLi - 1) {
        liDeger++;

        // Add "active" class to next image
        var activeLi = $('.slider li').eq(liDeger);
        activeLi.addClass('active');

        toplamWidth = liDeger * liWidth;
        $('div.slider ul').animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + toplamWidth + "px"
        }, 500, function() {
            // Remove "active" class from previous image after the animation
            activeLi.prev().removeClass('active') ;
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

And the "previous" arrow goes the other way

```
$('div.arrow a:nth-child(1)').click(function() {
    if (liDeger > 0) {
        liDeger--;

        // Add "active" class to previous image
        var activeLi = $('.slider li').eq(liDeger);
        activeLi.addClass('active');

        toplamWidth = liDeger * liWidth;
        $('div.slider ul').animate({
            marginLeft: '-' + toplamWidth + "px"
        }, 500, function() {
            // Remove "active" class from next image after the animation
             activeLi.next().removeClass('active') ;
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Then all you need is some CSS to hide everything but the active image:

```
div.slider ul li {
    visibility: hidden;
} 
div.slider ul li.active {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

And add a "active" class to the first list item in the HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul>
        <li class="slides active"><img src="resimler/resim1.jpg"></li>
    ...
</div>
```

Working example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRPEWg

Comment: Thank you for helping :)